# Connect to a hive database stored in the Hue web interface using jsp files

Tags: eclipse, web-services, jsp, hive, hue

I´m working on a dynamic web project in Eclipse using the tomcat server 8.5.

I´m trying to connect to a hive database that I created with the Hue web interface by using jsp files.

My approach is to define and use a datasource that lets me connect to the database stored in Hue.
So when I execute my eclipse project and start the tomcat server, the data stored in the database in Hue should be visible in my localhost browser.

My jsp file right now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"  pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"  url="jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default"  user="root"  password=""/>
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">SELECT * from test;</sql:query> 
</body>
</html>
```

However, I havent defined that datasource yet because I dont know how to create such a datasource.
And even if I have defined such a datasource, how exactly do I connect to the data in Hue?
This approach worked for MYSQL tables and a mysql driver, but these tables where local on my PC, whereas the hive database is stored in the Hue web interface.

Can I connect to the Hive database stored in the Hue web interface with this approach?

Or is there another, better way to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _"the hive database is stored in the Hue web interface"_ > nonsense. Hue is a Python interface to multiple back-ends, incl. HiveServer2 (query engine), Hive Metastore (front-end for a RDBMS storing table information), HDFS (the distributed file system storing the data files for tables etc), etc etc.

Comment: You have a dummy JDBC connection set up to reach HiveServer2 on `localhost`. That's a good start. Now find out on which server HS2 is running, how to authenticate, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found a solution.